# table view of entities in symfony2 with twig

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

I've been looking at various similiar questions and answers, but none fits this or solves my problem. I feel I'm missing something obvious because this seems to crazy simple and common. Anyways:

I want to build a table view from which the user can select entities for further processing. Obviously, I need to display more than just a name, I want to add a multitude of data.

The 'entity' form type seems the natural choice, so I've defined a form type including this:

```
    $builder->add('items', 'entity', array(
        'multiple'=>true,
        'expanded'=>true,
        'class'=>'MySiteBundle:Item', 'property'=>'name', 'query_builder'=>function(EntityRepository $er) use ($catagory) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('s')->where('s.category = :cat')->andWhere('s.available=true')->orderBy('s.name')->setParameters(array('cat'=>$category));
    }));
```

Thinking this would somehow give me access to the entity in twig. But no matter what I try, via form.items.vars or .get("value") or two dozen other things suggested to similar questions, nothing works.

All I want is a table with item data (name, price, etc. etc.) and I can't believe this is so difficult. What easy, obvious thing am I missing?

I need to use a form because there is other data the user needs to enter and I want to make use of validation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't get the access to the entities behind the `entity` type from a form view. Because of that, you need to fetch the items in a separate query. To make this easy, make the keys of the array of items correspond to their IDs. Provided you send the `items` array to the template, you could output it like this:

```
<table>
    {% for item in form.items %}
        {% set id = item.get('value') %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ form_widget(item) }}</td>
            <td>{{ items[id].name }}</td>
            <td>{{ items[id].category.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ items[id].available ? 'Yes' : 'No' }}</td>
            {# and so on ... #}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, that is the correct approach. I'd like to add that using indexed associations (http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/tutorials/working-with-indexed-associations.html) makes this very easy to implement.

Comment: It would be good if you could provide an example for `make the keys of the array of items correspond to their IDs`

Comment: Also, if you are using symfony 2.1 or upwards you should use `{% set id = item.vars['value'] %}`